# Boas práticas e uso de DateTime em Lista de ViewModels

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, datetime, viewmodel

Estou fazendo um sistema para o cliente, e ele dispensou o uso do fullcalendar, que seria prático. Com isso, eu criei em uma tabela com os campos AgendaId(int), e DataAgendamento(DateTime) anos para frente (umas 20000 linhas).

Com isso eu montei a seguinte ViewModel:

```
public class AgendaAgendamentoVM
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int? AgendamentoId { get; set; }
    public DateTime Date { get; set; }
    public int? ClienteId { get; set; }
    public string ClienteNome { get; set; }
}
```

E tenho uma segunda tabela de nome Reserva com os campos:

```
public class Reserva
    {
        public int ReservaId { get; set; }
        public int AgendaId { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public int ClienteId { get; set; }
        public string Servico { get; set; }

        public virtual Cliente Cliente { get; set; }
    }
```

E Clientes

```
public class Cliente
{
    public int ClienteId { get; set; }

    [Column(TypeName = "varchar(50)")]
    public string Nome { get; set; }

    [Column(TypeName = "varchar(50)")]
    public string Telefone { get; set; }

    [Column(TypeName = "varchar(50)")]
    public string Endereco { get; set; }

    [Column(TypeName = "varchar(50)")]
    public string Email { get; set; }

    public DateTime DataCadastro { get; set; }

}
```

O código da ViewModel abaixo retorna todos os dias a partir das 6 horas da manhã ate as 22 horas da noite:

```
 IList<AgendaAgendamentoVM> _listaAgendaVM = new List<AgendaAgendamentoVM>();

        if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(mes))
        {
            var data = DateTime.Parse(mes);
            ViewBag.Data = data;
            ViewBag.Ontem = data.AddDays(-1);
            ViewBag.Amanha = data.AddDays(1);

            var dias = await _context.Agenda
            .Where(x => x.DataAgenda >= data.AddHours(6))
            .Where(x => x.DataAgenda <= data.AddHours(22))
            .ToListAsync();


            foreach (var item in dias)
            {
                AgendaAgendamentoVM li = new AgendaAgendamentoVM();
                li.Id = item.AgendaId;
                li.Date = DateTime.Parse(item.DataAgenda.ToString());
                _listaAgendaVM.Add(li);
            }

            ViewData["ListaAgenda"] = _listaAgendaVM;
            return View();
```

A View:

```
@{
ViewBag.Title = "Agenda";
}

<form>
<input type="date" name="mes" required /> <input type="submit" value="Enviar" />
</form>
<div class="row m-1 p-2 bg-success rounded">

<div class="col-4">
    <a class="text-white" href="/Agenda/Index?mes=@String.Format("{0:d}", ViewBag.Ontem)"><</a>
</div>

<div class="col-4 text-center text-white font-weight-bolder">
    @String.Format("{0:d}", ViewBag.Data)
</div>


<div class="col-4 text-right">
    <a class="text-white" href="/Agenda/Index?mes=@String.Format("{0:d}", ViewBag.Amanha)">></a>
</div></div>

    <ul class="list-group m-1">
    @foreach (var item in ViewData["ListaAgenda"] as List<Camarim.Core.ViewModels.AgendaAgendamentoVM>)
{
    <li class="list-group-item"><a href="#?agendaid=@item.Id">@String.Format("{0:HH:mm}", item.Date) - @item.ClienteNome</a></li>

}
```

Só com a tabela **Agenda**, consigo exibir em uma view um calendário "navegável" conforme a imagem:

[image: View de uma ViewModel da tabela Agenda]

Ainda na tabela Reserva, tenho um campo ClienteId, onde eu retorno um cliente específico. Na Lista que faço da ViewModel, uso um  foreach chamando a tabela Reserva e Clientes, conforme a foto:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O problema disso é, ao fazer isso, a view deixa de exibir toda a lista das 6 as 22, apenas mostra os campos onde tem clientes agendados. Meu objetivo era deixar pelo menos desta forma:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Como posso fazer para chegar a esse objetivo: e/OU outra: Tem alguma outra forma de fazer isso sem usar o banco de dados para popular datas?